# Ember Duration Picker Component

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

Is there any Ember Duration Picker Component available to use as duration picker in which it picks only duration like in jquery duration picker.

[image]

Help me regarding this.

Comment: I would suggest searching on https://emberobserver.com

Comment: it looks there's none, maybe to include jquery picker to your app.

Answer (score 1):

To search addons, visit [EmberObserver](https://emberobserver.com) and [emberaddons.com](http://emberaddons.com). No result from my searchs.

If you want to use that `jquery` addon, look to [Ember Guide](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.11.0/components/the-component-lifecycle/#toc_integrating-with-third-party-libraries-with-code-didinsertelement-code) that shows how to integrate a third party library to your component.

Answer (score 0):

As long as jquery plugin that you need exists, it's not a problem to create a [component](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.11.0/components/defining-a-component/).